# Set Module name, Controller name, and Action name in Routes Zend framework 3?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3

I am New to Zend 3. i have multiple modules but I dont know how to route different module controller action.

```
'route' => '/[:module][/]dashboard[/][:action][/:id]',
```

the above route works fine in zend 2.4. but i cant able to find solution in zend 3

Answer (score 0):

In ZF3 every module should have its own namespace. So if you have multiple DashboardController in different modules, for each you have to define a route in each module.config.php like:

```
 'modulenameDashboard' => [
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/modulename/dashboard[/:action][/:id][/]',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => \Modname\Controller\DashboardController::class,
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ]
                ]
            ],
```

You can also generate this route in Module::getConfig()
Also, if you have only one DashboardController, there is no need to specify module in route, you only has to point specific controller class

```
 'dashboard' => [
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/dashboard[/:action][/:id][/]',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Modname\Controller\DashboardController::class,
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ]
                ]
            ],
```